# No such process (3) when not connected to a network (AF_ROUTE)

Tags: networking, c, route, bsd

When I am connected to a network, I can send a `struct rt_msghdr*` to the kernel and receive a corresponding route. However, when I disconnect from the network and try to send the same route message header, the socket fails at `send()` with `errno = ESRCH (3) No such process`.

Generic code: (Testing on MacOS)

```
int sd = create_socket(AF_ROUTE, IPPROTO_RAW, AF_UNSPEC);

memset(&buffer[0], 0, buffer.size());
struct rt_msghdr* rmh = (struct rt_msghdr*)(&buffer[0]);
rmh->rtm_msglen       = sizeof(struct rt_msghdr) + sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
rmh->rtm_version      = RTM_VERSION;
rmh->rtm_type         = RTM_GET;
rmh->rtm_addrs        = RTA_DST;
rmh->rtm_pid          = getpid();
rmh->rtm_seq          = 1;
struct sockaddr_in* sa_in = (struct sockaddr_in*)(rmh + 1);
sa_in->sin_len            = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
sa_in->sin_family         = AF_INET;

int status;
if ((status = send(sd, rmh, rmh->rtm_msglen, 0) < 0) {
    // process errno
    // * issue happens here when not connected to a network
}

// receive kernel response(s)
// process responses

close(sd);
```

I verified that the process ID (pid) is being set correctly in the header. `netstat -nr` returns the default route without issue when not connected to a network. I'm having trouble understanding why this code is dependent on network connectivity.

Comment: Don't have a Mac OS X box to test on, but I'm somewhat surprised netstat shows a default route w/o a network — I'd expect there not to be one (and that the error you're getting means as much). Curious what netstat gives as the default route.

Comment: @derobert That's reassuring to hear! These are the results of netstat on OSX without a network connection `default - fe80::%utun0 - UGcI - utun0` in the format "Destination, Gateway, Flags, Netif Expire"

Comment: fe80:: is an IPv6 address, but you're asking for IPv4 (AF_INET). So probably you'd get that if you asked for AF_INET6 (and changed to sockaddr_in6, etc.).

Comment: [BTW: You'll probably find much more knowledge about programming the OSX/BSD APIs on [so] — you should consider asking there, presuming of course someone else hasn't already asked. ]

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to try for the IPv6 route if the IPv4 route failed. Still no luck. :( I was about to ask on SO, but figured this was more specific to BSD. I'll ask there and see what I can dig up.